# Why can't I reference a static member from an inner class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a static class

```
namespace MyNameSpace{

    public static class MyStaticClass {

        public static string myStaticMember = "";

    }
}
```

I can reference myStaticMember in another class like this:

```
string varString = MyStaticClass.myStaticMember;
```

except if MyStaticClass is an inner class of the other class.

Why ?

Update: this is what I'd like to do

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class MyOuterClass
    {


        public static class MyStaticClass
        {

            public static string myStaticMember = "";

        }


        MyStaticClass.myStaticMember = "Hello";


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code? Is the inner class declared as `private`?

Comment: Can you post the actual code that is failing? I have no problem with doing what I *think* you're describing.

Comment: You can't just stick executable code anywhere inside a class body. It has to be in a method, constructor, property, indexer, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you need to reference it through the outer class:

```
string varString = MyOuterClass.MyStaticClass.myStaticMember
```

---

UPDATE:

The code you've posted won't compile because you are trying to access a field directly inside the outer class, every statement should be contained inside a method, you need to declare a method in the outer class in which you could access the inner class field.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static string myStaticMember = "";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyStaticClass.myStaticMember = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(MyStaticClass.myStaticMember);
    }
}
```

Comment: eRROR Message says myStaticMember is a field and is used like a type.

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile because you are trying to access a field directly inside the outer class, every code should be contained inside a method, you need to declare a method in the outer class in which you could access the inner class field.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: I can access any field inside a class, why wouldn't I be able to do so just when the class is inner static ?

Answer (score 2):

```
        MyStaticClass.myStaticMember = "Hello";
```

That's an assignment statement, not a declaration.  Statements must be written inside a method.  A suitable one would be the constructor for MyOuterClass:

```
    public MyOuterClass() {
        MyStaticClass.myStaticMember = "Hello";
    }
```

Comment: And how would I retrieve the value out of the constructor then ?

Comment: Erm, doesn't compute.  Use MyOuterClass.MyStaticClass.myStaticMember in other code to get the value of the static variable.